# (have a commitment) or (have another commitment)

Tags: word-choice

I have made up the examples below.

(1) Sorry, I can't fix your computer next week because I have **a** commitment.

(2) Sorry, I can't fix your computer next week because I have **another** commitment.

Which one is correct: "a" or "another" commitment?

Comment: The second one is more idiomatically correct and mainly heard.

Answer (score 1):

`Another` is correct here because you are saying that you have their commitment and also the other commitment.
Whenever you are adding two of the same thing together we use "another"

Comment: Thank you very much.